# Is it bad security to pre-filled all the signup fields for my users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a list of people with all their personal information (name, first name, date of birth, email, etc.). I created an account for each of these people in my database. I'm using Firebase.

Since I already have all my user's info, I don't want them to type it again when signing up to my website.

So I created a system using a custom token for authentication. I send them as a parameter of an URL to every one of my users.

1. When the user clicks on the link for the first time: he gets redirected to the signup page with all the fields pre-filled (name, date of birth, email, etc) except for the password. He types the password he wants and gets signed up.
2. When the user clicks on the link every other time: he gets redirected to the login page. A simple email + password interface with the email field already pre-filled. He types his password and gets logged in.

This is working great BUT I'm wondering: is this bad practice to do so?
Is this insecure to let anyone who gets the email create an account in the name of my user? Should I assume that someone, other than my user, may have total access to my user email account? Should I be prepared for this eventuality?

Comment: Might be better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, why are you showing them a signup screen if you already have their information? Just set a junk password and email them a change password link.

Comment: I'm showing them a signup page pre-filled to let them see and implicitly confirm their info. Also this seems to be more reassuring for the user. But even without these fields displayed, is it bad practice to send that kind of link to someone email account and presuming nobody else will click on it?

Answer (score 2):

> Since I already have all my user's info, I don't want them to type it again when signing up to my website.

If you already have the user's information, and you are allowed to process it, then it's a good practice to not let the user do something that it's already done.

> is this bad practice to do so?

Not at all. That seems to me like a practice that is present almost everywhere. If you want to edit the profile data, you always have the existing data already pre-filled. The user has just to verify it or change it if needed.

> Is this insecure to let anyone who gets the email create an account in the name of my user?

That sounds not like the best option if someone else can use that URL and create an account on behalf of the user. Most likely you should consider letting the user create the account only if it can validate the data through an SMS, or any other service that is specific to that user in particular.

> Should I assume that someone, other than my user, may have total access to my user email account? Should I be prepared for this eventuality?

Yes indeed. You should always prepare for that. Never trust the users. There's not a perfect world out there.